# PHP MySQL query returning random values

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm very noob in php and SQL and I want to solve this weird problem I'm facing :S

Here I show you the code:

```
<?php
require 'dbdata.php';
$gp = $_POST["GP"];   
$DBH1 = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$RQ1 = $DBH1->prepare("SELECT GgID,ID FROM Usuarios WHERE GgID='$gp'");
$RQ1 -> execute();
$row1 = $RQ1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
if(($RQ1 -> rowCount()) >0){
    echo $row1[1] . "////@@";
    echo "Login";// Username is taken
    $DBH = null;
}
else{
    echo "0" . "////@@";
    echo "Register";
    $DBH = null;
}
?>
```

Now I want to explain you what should it do and what randomly do. The script is a simple one, I make a post with a string, that string has to be on the database and the script return me the content of the ID column, BUT, a 10% times it returns me a random value that has no relation with the post i do but 90% times returns the correct value... what's wrong here?

**PS: I have a similar script that runs simultaneously but with other post, is this related with the error?**

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Do you update the DB via another means ?

Comment: You're setting `$DBH = null;` but you never instantiate that variable. What is it for?

Comment: @JayBlanchard f*ck is from the other script xd... is that making the error??

Comment: @Rabin I make the same of that script with another row, so I'm just selecting.

Comment: You'll have to test it to make sure.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the advice!!

Comment: @JayBlanchard tested, same problem :/ I don't understand if the other script make the goal why this script is giving me random values? the most times this happens is the first time i run the game, then is 90%/10% but is annoying :(